# Restangular option to update an object without getting it from server

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have started using Restangular and it seems to be a very good library. However I have the following query. In order to update an object I am using the below code

```
Restangular.one("accounts", $scope.accountEdit.id).get().then(function(account) {
    account = Restangular.copy($scope.accountEdit);
    account.put();
});
```

In the above code I have to do a get request to the server and then update it. Is there a better way to just avoid the server call as I would like to update the object from my scope to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `customPUT` like this,

```
Restangular.one("accounts").customPUT($scope.accountEdit, $scope.accountEdit.id).then(function(account) {
     TO-DO
});
```

> **customPUT([elem, path, params, headers])**: Does a PUT to the specific
>   path. Optionally you can set params and headers and elem. Elem is the
>   element to post. If it's not set, it's assumed that it's the element
>   itself from which you're calling this function.

besides this you can **extend your object with Restangular** which gives you same result as your callback function did...

```
angular.extend($scope.accountEdit, Restangular.one("accounts", $scope.accountEdit.id));
$scope.accountEdit.put();
```